# Installed multiboot Ubuntu 16.04 crashed ( after a half hour of browsing with Firefox )

Tags: dual-boot, graphics

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 7 OS.

[image: ubuntu crash]

The above shown error happened after a half hour of browsing using the new Ubuntu.

One of a sudden, the monitor shows coloured dots and dashes and is flickering. Now I cannot have any control over this. No mouse or keyboard can be imputed, not even reboot from screen due to the above crash. I can only reboot from CPU box.

Should I buy a new graphic card or RAM? And how much? Isn't Ubuntu smooth on lower RAM and no graphic card? This is the reason I did not purchased graphic card in the first place.

Please, help me make my Ubuntu usable again!

Here are my specs: 500GB of hard disk space, Intel Core i3, 2GB RAM and no graphic card.

Comment: Does "Ubuntu 16.04 with windows 7 os" mean that you *dual boot* Ubuntu and Windows? In that case, is the graphics working with Windows? Does the graphics work, when you boot Ubuntu from the install USB drive or DVD disk?

Comment: Pardon me for waiting too long to reply.Yes dual booted system.Windows is working fine without graphic card .No I don't have graphic card and live USB drive is crashing the same way after 30-40 min into starting the system.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that Windows works well indicates a software problem, but it could be a hardware problem too, for example if the computer is running hotter and/or uses more power with Ubuntu.

You can try with an Ubuntu flavour with a **lighter desktop environment**.

- Lubuntu with the ultra light LXDE
- Ubuntu MATE with medium light MATE
- Xubuntu with the medium light XFCE

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

You can also **check if the RAM is good**. Boot the computer into BIOS mode and run **memtest** (one of the options from the boot menu in BIOS mode). Let it run overnight. One error is too much.

**A clean computer runs cooler**. I would open the computer and clean it from dust. You can use compressed air to remove the dust. (A vacuum-cleaner might work too if you are *very careful*, but many people warn that it creates *static electricity*, and it might destroy the computer.)

It is also important to provide space around the computer for the air flow.

Comment: Before installing Ubuntu already did the memtest. What do you mean by running night it takes only 1mins. This is already refurbished computer almost clean inside . A new motherboard. I would try your guide and reply if the problem persist. And thank you for suggestions and help.

Comment: Memtest runs several tests, and unless you have a supercomputer, it takes much more than one minute to run all of them once. It is a good idea to run the tests more than once in order to test that the memory is working well during a long time, particularly when you have this kind of problem after half an hour. Anyway, it is often recommended to test overnight, to get the RAM tested thoroughly. - I have good experiences of refurbished computers, and I hope that you will solve the problem.  - Please come back if necessary. Maybe someone else is able to spot the problem and suggest a solution.

Comment: No luck !! only windows and windows live cds are running smoothly. I tried all newest Ubuntu lite flavours they crashed on so installed debian on my phone and adjusting myself . Waiting to buy a new RAM stick in a purchase offer.

Comment: *Please tell us about the graphics chip: brand name and model*. If it is built into the Core i3 processor, please specify which model and 'generation' of Core i3 - Someone might recognize it and have a solution for that particular kind of graphics hardware. Maybe you find something useful via this link: https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=332